# 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll' error message?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have made a quiz that is supposed to save the students name and score to the correct table in an access database. There are 3 tables. I have tried to connect and code the database but I keep getting the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   Additional information: Conversion from string "INSERT INTO Class1 ([StudentScor" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I have tried to find solutions to this error however, I don't fully understand. Here is my code for the save button which should save the name and score to the correct table:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    StudentClass = cbSelectClass.SelectedItem
    Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    DataFile = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "StudentScores.accdb")
    ConnString = Provider & DataFile
    If StudentClass = "Class1" Then
        Strng = "INSERT INTO Class1 ([StudentScores], [Score]) Values('" + CType(txtName.Text, String) + CType(Score, Integer)
    ElseIf StudentClass = "Class2" Then
        Strng = "INSERT INTO Class2 ([Student Scores], [Score]) Values('" + CType(txtName.Text, String) + CType(Score, Integer)
    ElseIf StudentClass = "Class3" Then
        Strng = "INSERT INTO Class3([StudentScores], [Score]) Values('" + CType(txtName.Text, String) + CType(Score, Integer)
    End If
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Strng, MyConnection)
    MyConnection.Open()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
        txtName.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        cmd.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
    End Try
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of unnecessary CType casting going on. Textbox.Text is already of type string. You don't want to cast Score to an Integer, because you are concatenating to a string. Also, get used to the String.Format function, as it'll help code readability and will help you find your mis-named DB column name. Don't be afraid of white space for readability:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Const SQL_INSERT As String = "INSERT INTO {0} (StudentScores, Scores) VALUES ('{1}', {2})"

    Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    DataFile = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "StudentScores.accdb")
    ConnString = Provider & DataFile

    Dim sql As String = String.Format(SQL_INSERT, cbSelectClass.SelectedItem, txtName.Text.Trim, Score.ToString)

    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, MyConnection)
    MyConnection.Open()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
        txtName.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        cmd.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
    End Try
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Now, you'll have to look into SQL Injection to correct that, and you should use the Using statement to initialize the Connection and Command objects.